# proving set theory union statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I just started learning set theory in discrete mathematics and it's soon enough before i get stuck at my first supplementary question.

> Prove $( A \cap B) \cup ( A \cap B^c  ) = A$

How do i even start this question?

I checked the various law in this chapter but I've found no link to even start off this question?

What are the things i need to take note when doing such proving.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: use de Morgan's law. What is $B \cup B^c$ ?

Comment: Unfortunately, demorgan only has 2 law which is (A∪B)c = Ac ∪ Bc and (A∩B)c  = Ac ∩ Bc. is there a way to link this to the above question?

Comment: That's what my notes written only. I guess i'm only allowed to use the laws in my notes? Please enlighten.

Comment: OK, ignore my first hint, because here's a better one: use the distributive law (there are two; use the relevant one). Again, what is $B \cup B^c$?

Answer (score 1):

Go with the definitions:

$$A\cap B=\{x:x\in A\land x\in B\}\quad\text{and}\quad A\cap B^c=\{x:x\in A\land x\notin B\}$$

Then

$$(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)=\{x:(x\in A\land x\in B) \lor (x\in A\land x\notin B)\}$$

And we know that

1. $a\lor(b\land c)=(a\lor b)\land (a\lor c)$, distribution of $\lor$ over $\land$
2. $a\land(b\lor c)=(a\land b)\lor (a\land c)$, distribution of $\land$ over $\lor$
3. $a\lor (a\land b)=a$, this is called an "absortion" rule because no matter what $a$ is true
4. $a\land (a\lor b)=a$, second absortion rule

Then

$$\begin{align}&(x\in A\land x\in B) \lor (x\in A\land x\notin B)=\\&((x\in A\land x\in B)\lor x\in A)\land((x\in A\land x\in B)\lor x\notin B)=\\&(x\in A)\land((x\in A\land x\in B)\lor x\notin B)=\\&(x\in A)\land ((x\in A\lor x\notin B)\land(x\in B\lor x\notin B))=\\&(x\in A)\land (x\in A\lor x\notin B)=\\&x\in A\end{align}$$

Then we have that

$$(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)=\{x:x\in A\}=A$$

Answer (score 0):

$$n(A)=1 + 3$$
$$n(B)=2+3$$
$$n(A \cap B) =3 $$
$$n(B^c)=1+4$$
$$n( A \cap B^c  ) =1$$
$$n( A \cap B) \cup ( A \cap B^c  ) = 1 +3 =n(A)$$

$(1,2,3,4)$ are not integral number they are used for representation.

[image: Venn Diagram]